# ElasticSearch Nest 2.x - Performance issue, how to disable audit trail?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm running search queries using Elasticsearch client NEST 2.
Queries are running fine but inspecting the response I can see that a huge time is spent auditing the query while the ES operation itself is done in a snap.

Here is an example of a request/response :

> Succesful low level call on POST: /document/ElasticDocument/_search
>
> Audit trail of this API call:
>    - HealthyResponse: Node: http://my-ES-server.com:9200/ **Took: 00:00:00.3040912**
>   Request:
>   {"from":0,"size":1,"query":{"term":{"Id":{"value":1568}}}}
>   Response:
>   {**"took":16**,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":9.345218,"hits":[{"_index":"document","_type":"ElasticDocument","_id":"1568","_score":9.345218,"_source":{........}}]}}

We can see that the audit took 304ms while the ES search took only 16.

My question is, is there anyway to disable this audit trail or tweak the configuration to effectively improve the performance ?

I had a look at the source code and found out that the audit trail operation is triggered by the ElasticsearchResponse's property DebugInformation but couldn't find how to disable it.

My configuration is pretty straight forward :

```
var node = new Uri("http://my-ES-server.com:9200/");

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);

settings.DefaultIndex("document");
settings.DefaultTypeNameInferrer(p => p.Name);
settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

settings.DisableDirectStreaming(); 

this.elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

And then my nest call :

```
var response = this.elasticClient.Search<ElasticDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Term("Id", documentId))
    .From(0)
    .Take(1)
);
```

For information, when I'm running the queries against a local ES store (populated with same data) audit trail takes ~60ms which is better but still huge comparing to the ES search operation.

Many thanks,

Mickael

Answer (score 1):

[Audit Trail information is built when the `.DebugInformation` property is accessed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/2.x/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Responses/ElasticsearchResponse.cs#L100-L105).

[`took` in the response is the time taken on the cluster for Elasticsearch to *execute* the search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html) and **doesn't include**

1. time to serialize the request
2. network latency going to the selected Elasticsearch node
3. network latency coming back from the selected Elasticsearch node
4. time to deserialize the response

Contrastly, the `Took` time that you see in the audit trail is a *rough* (in the sense it is calculated with an [`IDateTimeProvider`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/date-time-providers.html) implementation that uses `DateTime` precision by default) **total time between**

1. getting a node from the [`IConnectionPool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/connection-pooling.html)
2. serializing the request
3. sending the request to the node
4. time take on the Elasticsearch node
5. receiving the response back from the node
6. deserializing the response

Because of differences in network latency, the number reported in the audit trail could vary in different environments. Further, it's likely to be higher on the first request because of the initialization of caches used for member access by the json serializer.

As an aside, looking at your configuration, unless you need to access the request or response body bytes, **do not call `.DisableDirectStreaming()`**; this copies the request and response to a `MemoryStream` internally in order to make the bytes available.

Comment: Feel free to submit an issue on github to discuss: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues

Comment: Ok thanks, that was exactly my thoughts but I was hoping there could be a way to not access this DebugInformation property so I could save some ms.
Using stopwatch I can see that almost all of the time spent in my search is caused by the audit trail but sadly I think I'll have to deal with this...


Does 60ms of audit trail seems reasonable to you for a local env ?
Making 3 calls in a row will give me 60ms, 1ms, 1ms of audit trail but waiting a few between each call gives me 60ms , 60ms, 60ms


DisableDirectStreaming was only used to show the "pure" ES took information.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding; the cost of _capturing_ the information for the audit trail should be negligible i.e. it is not contributing to the 304ms you see in your question which is the combination of getting a node from connection pool, serializing the request, network latency for the request, time to execute on Elasticsearch (`took` time), network latency for the response, deserialization of the response. _Building_ of the audit trail information happens when you access `DebugInformation` so if you don't need the audit information, don't access the property :)

Comment: `took` is available on `ISearchResponse<T>` in the `Took` property

Comment: Performing the sames search query using sense, I have a response within 18ms (15ms for the ES execution) which include steps 3,4,5 from your above answer (http://postimg.org/image/j65yymeon/)
So this should mean that nest takes a hell of a time for serialization/deserialization, but again using only the lowlevel client I also have a long response time even if there's only post data operation.
I'm having a hard time figuring out where the response time difference between nest and sense comes from :(

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it is not about Audit trail. The point is that NEST uses by default `Accept: application/json` header. When you set `EnableHttpCompression()` on your client, NEST starts to use `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header and that's correct.

This is my client initialization code:

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost.:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
    .EnableHttpCompression()
    .PrettyJson();
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Comment: Sense is also communicating with application/json plus my ES nodes are not configured for compression so I don't think this is where my problem comes from.
I'll still give it a try and let you know the outcome.